# Stata: How to plot groups of variables side-by-side in stacked percent bar chart with subgraphs?

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, stata, barplot

I did a cluster analysis of categorical variables and want to plot the result in a summary graph. There are three groups of variables that contain 'dummy variables'. I'm able to plot one group of these 'dummy variables' with subgraphs by cluster membership:

[image: stacked percentages of variable group 1 by cluster membership]

```
graph bar a_group1 b_group1 c_group1 d_group1 e_group1 f_group1 x_ group1,
by(, legend(off)) xsize(6) ysize(8) aspectratio(1.2)
by(clus_8_ward_gower) stack percent
```

How do I add x_group2 and x_group3 that they are displayed each side-by-side by cluster membership (see sketch, ignoring the 'count' bar).

Is it possible to add a fourth variable next to the percentage-bars that displays a mean on a second scale (see whole sketch).

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose best would be to install the Stata module [combineplot](http://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/S457823.htm): The aim of
combineplot is to give a convenience command offering modest automation whenever each graph is of the same kind and different plots are for different
variables. 
You did not provide any data, so, here a toy example:

```
ssc install combineplot , replace
sysuse auto, clear
combineplot (mpg price) (rep78 foreign), sequence(a b c d) seqopts(caption(, color(red))): graph box @y, over(@x)
```

which renders:
[image]